# I am building a BSC list generator where I connect to the blockchain to read all wallets and determine the amount of transactions in that wallet

Tags: blockchain, transactions, javascript, evm

I have done the research and can't find any method which checks the entire blockchain or a specified amount of wallets to check the transaction numbers of that wallet to spit into a list. Can anyone help with this?